# How to set timeout for apache thrift JS client calls?

Tags: javascript, thrift

I have the following client code:

```
var transport = new Thrift.Transport("/api/thrift/");
var protocol = new Thrift.Protocol(transport);
var client = new ApiClient(protocol);
client.callApi(myInput);
```

(Very similar to the [tutorial](https://thrift.apache.org/tutorial/js))

Before trying to invoke the server (`callApi`), I'd like to set the timeout for the call. **How do I do set the client's timeout?**